# Setting local persistence for firebase phone authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble setting persistence to local for my phone authentication in this firebase SDK and react-native project. I've tried putting

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
```

in many places, as well as other things but it's still not working. Do I have to implement some sort of async storage feature, and if so which one?

Here is the code used for logging in on the screen where users login. Right now login works but the persistence is only at the session.

```
const [phoneNumberWithCode, setPhoneNumberWithCode] = useState('+1');
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
const [code, setCode] = useState('');
const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
const [confirming, setConfirming] = useState(true);

const press = () => {
    setPhoneNumber('');
    setCode('');
    setConfirming(true);
}

const sendVerification = () => {
    const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
    phoneProvider
    .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberWithCode, recaptchaVerifier.current)
    .then(setVerificationId);
    setConfirming(!confirming);
    setCode('');
};

const confirmCode = () => {
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId,
        code
    );
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then(() => {
        setCode('');
        checkIfPhoneExists(phoneNumberWithCode).then((userExists) => {
            if (userExists) {
                navigation.navigate('Threads');
            } else {
                navigation.navigate('EnterInfo');
            }
        })
        createAccountIfNotUser(phoneNumberWithCode);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    console.log(auth, firebase.auth())

};
```

and here is the code for how I setup my firebase SDK authentication in the firebaseConfig file:

```
export const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```